# Filter date time in json based on date

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a code that has date time in a json, And I want to filter the json and show the data where `date` from `datetime` is greater than today's `date`.

Here is my code.

```js
var data = [{ 
  datetime: "2021-08-09T06:00:00.000Z",
  id: "1"
}, { 
  datetime: "2021-06-07T02:00:00.000Z",
  id: "2"
}, { 
  datetime: "2021-08-04T11:00:00.000Z",
  id: "3"
}, { 
  datetime: "2021-08-04T10:00:00.000Z",
  id: "4"
}, { 
  datetime: "2021-08-05T12:55:00.000Z",
  id: "5"
}, { 
  datetime: "2020-08-10T13:30:00.000Z",
  id: "6"
}]

data = data.filter(item=> { return new Date(item.datetime).getDate() > new Date().getDate()});

console.log(data);
```

it should print every thing apart from `id 3, 4 and 6`. Also when I do a `getDate()`, I think it only considers `DD` from `MMDDYYYY`, that's why `6` is getting printed. what would be the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a typo:

```
data = data.filter(item=> { return new Date(item.datatime).getDate() > new Date().getDate()});
//                                                  ^
//                                               datetime
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick catch brother. Now I'm another issue, Updated my question and see the result. I've added another date `2020-08-10T13:30:00.000Z` and it is also printing as the date is greater (which is currently being checked) but the year is old which shouldn't show up.

Comment: @Rakesh you could slice the ISO string and compared it to today's date ISO string: `data = data.filter(({ datetime }) => datetime.slice(0, 10) > new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10));` that's going to compare each `datetime` `YYYY-MM-DD` against today's `YYYY-MM-DD`

Comment: @MauricioRobayo That's a good solution. [Here's another idea](https://jsben.ch/GTKfG) that is a little more performant.

Answer (score 0):

```js
data = data.filter(item => {
  const date = new Date(item.datetime);
  const today = new Date();

  return date.getUTCFullYear() * 10000 + date.getUTCMonth() * 100 + date.getUTCDate() > today.getUTCFullYear() * 10000 + today.getUTCMonth() * 100 + today.getUTCDate();
});
```